# need to show/hide a div element on page load based on Boolean Expression

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to load a div based on localStorage Expression stored prior coming to the webpage. What would be an easy way to show a div if the boolean is true for example? I have looked at many examples, but most of them seams to be a bit confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some DOM manipulation framework (jQuery for example)?

Comment: On a technical note: localStorage doesn't store anything other than text. If you think you're storing an expression or a boolean, then be aware that this is not the case.

Comment: And by `expression` do you mean like boolean expressions like `a > 50 && b - 5 == 3` or what?

Comment: I meant by boolean expression true or false

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check for the variable on localStorage...

```
var item = window.localStorage.getItem('item') === "true";
if(item){
    //load your div;
}else{
    //do stuff
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8vjF/3/)

Comment: Yes, you're right. At first i thought he only wanted to check if the item was persisted on localStorage. Thanks for the correction

Comment: So I have to check this against the string than boolean?

Comment: Yes. As stated by @T.J.Crowder and Mike over there, localStorage only store itens as strings

Comment: You're right, @T.J.Crowder , sorry about that, i'm a little bit aerial today

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz: LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple helper functions that will help you to save objects/boolean etc. to localStorage

```
function SetObject(key, value) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets object to localStorage as <key, value> pair
    /// This function will automatically stringify given object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key object</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value object</param>

    try  {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        console.log("Set Data [" + key + "] Value");
        console.log(value);
    } catch (exception) {
        if (exception.name === 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR' || exception.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') {
            console.error("Quota exceeded! Clear localStorage to solve problem. WARNING: Clearing localStorage will delete all user data.");
        } else {
            console.error("Unknown error while trying to set an item \"" + key + "\" with value: ");
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
};

function GetObject(key) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets object from localStorage as value for given key
    /// This function will automatically parse localStorage value and return object type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key object</param>
    /// <returns>Object from localStorage that corresponds to given key</returns>

    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    var parsedValue = value && JSON.parse(value);
    console.log("Get Data [" + key + "] of Value");
    console.log(parsedValue);
    return parsedValue;
};
```

You can then use them to retrieve/save object/boolean value to localStorage

```
// This will be executed when document DOM finished loading
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Retrieve 'SomePropertyKey' value from localStorage and 
    // compare check if it's 'true'
    if (GetObject("SomePropertyKey") == true) {
        // jQuery call to change div's style 'display' to value 'block'
        $("#divId").show();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="divId" style="display: none;">...</div>
```